# Dereferencing id of an object to retrieve said object from a nested table - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have an issue retrieving an object with the `DEREF` word. I am sure it is a simple answer, I just haven't been able to get my head around what I'm doing wrong. My database is as follows:

I have the following types in a database of Students and their respective academic marks:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE TSUBJECT AS OBJECT 
(  

codeSubject NUMBER,
name VARCHAR2(20)

)
```

and the above object type for academic subjects is referenced in the following object type, which stores marks and references a particular TSUBJECT object type:

```
 create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE TMARKS OBJECT 
    (  
    
    lineNumber number, 
    codeSubject ref TSUBJECT, 
    marksArray TMARKSARRAY -- JUST AN ARRAY OF ACADEMIC MARKS
    )
```

and I have a table which is made of `TMARKS` object types, which will be nested in the `Students` table as a field called `nestedTable`.

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE MARKS_TABLE
AS TABLE OF TMARKS;
```

The `Students` table is a regular table of students' personal details, the only important field now is the last field of the table which is the `nestedTable` of type MARKS_TABLE :

The procedure:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE showStudentMarks(idStudent VARCHAR2) AS 

nestedT Students.nestedTable%type;

marks TMARKS:=  TMARKS(NULL,NULL,NULL);

subject TSUBJECT:=  TSUBJECT(NULL,NULL,NULL);

BEGIN

select nestedTable into nestedT from Students where ID=idStudent;

For i in 1..nestedT .count
loop

marks:=nestedT(i);

-- subject:=deref(marks.codeSubject); DOESNT WORK !

dbms_output.put_line('Number of Line: ' || marks.lineNumber); -- WORKS FINE 
dbms_output.put_line('First Mark for subject xx: ' || marks.marksArray(1)); -- WORKS FINE


End loop;

NULL;
    
END showStudentMarks;
```

Basically retrieving `marks.lineNumber` works, retrieving `marks.marksArray(1)` works, but `deref(marks.codeSubject)` doesn't, and I need to obtain the name of the subject from the TSUBJECT object type, supossedly by dereferencing it using `deref(marks.codeSubject).name` but it doesn't seem to work or most probably I am using the wrong syntax for it. Thanks

Comment: From [the documentation Padders referred to](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/functions-and-operators-useful-with-objects.html#GUID-6CD85D07-1E06-4E42-A582-68F478040A39): "Note: In PL/SQL the VALUE, REF and DEREF functions can appear only in a SQL statement." (Also, it would be helpful to include the error you get rather than just "doesn't work"; and the DDL for the missing table and type.)

Comment: thank you for the info about DEREF and REF only appearing in SQL statements. The error I get is  - `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to DEREF`

Answer (score 3):

You haven't stated a version of Oracle, nor have you provided a complete definition of the problem, and what you have posted doesn't compile. Where, for example is the DDL for the STUDENT and SUBJECT table(s) and the TMARKSARRAY type?

Anyway, unfortunately DEREF doesn't work exactly the same in PL/SQL (see docs) you probably just want...

```sql
SELECT DEREF (marks.codesubject)
INTO   subject
FROM   DUAL;
```

Note though that (although object-relational features are rarely used) it is generally considered a good idea to use SQL to traverse object-relational schemas as far as possible, the syntax is arguably richer and the optimizer has more flexibility in how it accesses the data. A similar traversal in SQL might resemble the below...

```sql
SELECT s.id student#,
       nt.linenumber mark#,
       DEREF (nt.codesubject).codesubject subject#,
       DEREF (nt.codesubject).name subject_name,
       m.COLUMN_VALUE mark
FROM   students s,
       TABLE (s.nestedtable) nt,
       TABLE (nt.marksarray) m
WHERE  s.id = 1;
```

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=13ef5809603d3a382cbcf6c3f75b820f) showing your first approach in action. You beat me to an answer but might as well not waste what I'd started! Feel free to include in your answer, modify, etc. *8-)